# SceneManager.LoadScene doesn't function for 2nd monitor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently running a dual-monitor Unity game setup, camera Display 1 on main monitor, Display 2 on second. When I load my duo monitor scene directly at build it works, but when I load it through SceneManager (As one does because of intros) Only Display 1 is shown.

I load my scene using the following:

```
SceneManager.UnloadScene(0);
SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
```

Is this an Unity bug, or am I missing a step activating my second display?

Comment: Have you tried doing `SceneManager.LoadScene(1, LoadSceneMode.Additive)` and then wait for the scene to load before unloading the old scene?

Comment: Yes, same result.

Comment: Unity currently has some serious bugs (in the EDITOR, when "Play" in the editor) with multi-monitor systems.  Perhaps that's relevant?  Does it work OK as an actual build?

Comment: The editor works as expected. All regarding to this post is build related.

Comment: Did you try my answer? Did it work if you call `Activate`?

Answer (score 0):

Force the Camera to activate after scene has finished loading.

```
void Start()
{
    Camera camera2 = GameObject.Find("Cam2").GetComponent<Camera>();
    camera2.targetDisplay = 1;
    Display.displays[1].Activate();
}
```

Well, `Display.displays[1].Activate();` alone should fix this but the other code is to make sure that the Camera's `targetDisplay` is assigned.

Comment: Already had the Display.displays[1].Activate(); code inserted (forgot to mention), but even with your added code the result remains the same.